# Cant connect to MySQL, wrong code?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I have tried to connect to my db, but nothing works...

This is the code that I have created:

```
$name ='testdb';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$host = 'localhost';

$link = new mysqli($name, $user, $password, $host);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$mail = $_POST ['mail'];

$name = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$message = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$mail = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Message, Mail) VALUES ('$name','$message', '$mail')";

$result = $link->query($sql);
```

I have allready double-checked all the spellings.
Can anyone give me some tips? I may have gone blind.

Comment: Firstly, you should enable [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/6140684) if not already because it will help you understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you did not initialize `mysqli` connection properly

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);//display all errors   

$name ='testdb';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$host = 'localhost';

$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $name);

Use prepared statements(Prevents SQL injection)

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Message, Mail) VALUES (?,?,?)";//placeholders (3placeholders for 3values)
$statement = $link->prepare($sql);//prepare query. returns true/false
$statement->bind_param('sss',$name, $message, $mail);//you dont need to escape anymore
$statement->execute(); //execute safely
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `mysqli` is the hostname, you swapped `hostname` and `databasename` [Connect to MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $name);
```

You can also use prepared statement, to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks)

> A [prepared statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) is a feature used to execute the same (or similar) SQL statements repeatedly with high efficiency.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Message, Mail) VALUES (?,? ?)";
$stmt =  $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$name, $message, $mail);
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result) {
    // query was successful
}else {
    // query failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this below code it will help you

```
$name ='testdb';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$host = 'localhost';

$link = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$name);
// Check connection
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
} 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$mail = $_POST ['mail'];

$name = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$message = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$mail = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Message, Mail) VALUES ('$name','$message', '$mail')";



if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
}

$link->close();
```

To learn basic things in PHP and MYSQL refer this link
https://www.w3schools.com/php/